# PHP file_get_contents(file.php); execute PHP code in file

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm currently having an issue, where I have some php code in a file and calling that file from another file.

so:

index.php is calling file.php and file.php has some php code in it.

The reason I'm using file_get_contents, is that I have code in index.php that only needs to read some of the content in file.php, designated by  tags. Based on teh section tag trigged by the ($_GET['identifier']); that section within the file.php is the only section displayed

Example code in file.php:

```
<?php
//simplified php code
var $item = "hello";
var $item2 = "Hola";
var $item3 = "おはよ";
?>

<section id="content">
<?php echo $item1; ?>  
</section>
<section id="content2">
<?php echo $item2; ?>
</section>
<section id="content3">
<?php echo $item3; ?>
</section>
?>
```

code in index.php:

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.php');
if (isset($_GET['item'])) {
$section = $_GET['item'];
} else {
$section = 'content';
}
$delimiter = '<section id="' . $section . '">';
$start = explode($delimiter, $content);
$end = explode("</section>", $start[ 1 ] );
echo $end[0];
```

so if the browser url shows index.php?item=content2 , it should show the content from section ID named content2, along with the PHP code in that file, executed.

currently, if I do this, nothing is displayed, and a view source, show the php code

Comment: You're going to need to redesign your approach I think, its not practical to file_get_contents a local php file and partially execute it. lets assume `eval` is out of the question like it should be, includes are going to be needed, or separate files for each of your section, or to create a class to contain all the separate tasks you have.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a degree of templating here?

Comment: it some what a template thing happening. its using the same CSS (each section), that is defined, in the index.php file. So the "sections" are just content that will need to fill in.

trying to reduce as much as possible, and don't want to put 30 items into 30 separate files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To execute the code before you get the contents, you either need to `include` and capture the output:

```
ob_start();
include('file.php');
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

Or get the file by URL (probably not the best idea and not portable):

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://example.com/file.php');
```

Comment: OMG "Doh" moment. sorry, I forgot about ob_start()  and ob_get_clean(); !!

Thanks, this actually fixes it!